# nginx passenger, setting the umask

Tags: nginx, debian, phusion-passenger, umask

I was wondering how to set the umask for nginx or passenger or both processes. A search seems to only bring up Apache. Any help would be very much appreciated! (This is on Debian.)

Comment: Similar older question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584021/nginx-php-fpm-umask-setting

Comment: @berbt that's for apache and php. But I'm asking for nginx and passenger. It is relevant.

Comment: Nope, is for nginx without passenger.